# Why does "window.open('', '_blank', 'noreferrer')" result in "about:blank#blocked"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, browser, window.open

I don't understand why the new window opens in this location.

Also if I assign the new window to a variable, its value is null:

`const win = window.open('', '_blank', 'noreferrer'); // win === null`.

it happened to me on chrome 111.0.0.

Why is this happening?
And what is the meaning of about:blank#blocked, under what circumstances does it appear?

Comment: May be you have some kind of adblocker plugin installed? I have Google Chrome *Version 111.0.5563.64* your code seems working. Just used url `const win = window.open('https://example.com', '_blank', 'noreferrer');`.

Comment: I don't have any plugins/extension.
In my example the url is an empty string, in yours it is a valid url.

Comment: Don't use window.open. Either open a new window/tab using a normal `<a>` (which you can make on the fly and click all on the JS size) if you're using it to load a true page, or show a modal if you're using it as a faux-dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version of browsers this action must be initiated by the user to enhance security and prevent undesired pop-ups (for example, advertisement).

**Attach an event listener to the button, which will execute your cod**e. This should ensure the expected functionality.

If you intend to execute the code **without direct user interaction**, it is a **good practice to inform the user and request confirmation** by providing an acceptance button.

There is a specific time interval after a user action within which you can execute your code. This interval varies across browsers and cannot be controlled. The general recommendation here is to call window.open() as close to the user action as possible.

This principle applies not only to window.open() but also to other scenarios like a working with a clipboard.